# Evaluate a variable from a function and assign the new variable into base Workspace

Tags: matlab

I have a GUI that takes users typed-in equations such as `delta_P=C1-C2;velocity=diff(y)./diff(x);` all in one string delimited and terminated by `;`.  Then, within the GUI function, I pull in `C1`, `C2`, `x`, and `y` in and I want to evaluate to generate `delta_P` and `velocity` and assign them into the base Workspace.  My problem is I don't know `delta_P` and `velocity` ahead of time so that I can't just do:

```
assignin('base','delta_P',C1-C2);
```

I need to break down the string to identify the new variable names left of the equal signs and assign to them what are right of the equal signs into the base Workspace?

I condition an input string with one or more statements so that there is no space and no carriage return.  Then, I tried the following:

```
str_in = 'delta_P=C1-C2;velocity=diff(y)./diff(x);'
str_sp = strsplit(str_in,';');
str_sp = str_sp(1:end-1); % last ';' results in an empty char
```

Then, this is where I get lost:

`cellfun(@(c1,c2)assignin('base',c1(1:c2-1),c1(c2+1:end)),str_sp,cellfun(@(c)strfind(c,'='),str_sp,'uni',0),'uni',0);`

1. It just doesn't look efficient
2. It still doesn't work as c1(c2+1:end) is also a string
3. I tried `eval(c1(1:c2-1))`, but MATLAB complains C1,C2,x, and y are undefined.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use [`evalin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) to evaluate the user's expression in the base workspace? All variables the user types in would be available there, and any assignments would automatically create new variables.

Comment: @CrisLuengo this GUI is launched from a figure from which raw data are transported to the GUI (line_h.XData and line_h.YData) along with a user's equation.  So, they are not readily available in the base Workspace.  Now I thought more about it, it was really a question of breaking down the user's equation string by using regexp, strsplit, etc.  Let me edit the problem.

Comment: And you don't want to copy `line_h.XData` as `x` in the base workspace because you might overwrite something? How about examining the output of `who`, before and after evaluating the user's expression, to see which variables are new?

Comment: Though this sort of tool is very dangerous, if the user types `strsplit=y;` as their expression, then your function will break because the function `strsplit` will be shadowed. Input validation becomes very important here. This doesn't happen if you do `evalin` in the base workspace, variables there don't affect the working of your own function.

Comment: @CrisLuengo only issue will be my laziness to clean those generated variables from XData and YData.  User can have many lines.  Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should evaluate *the expression* in the current workspace, and then evaluate *the assignment* in the base workspace.

Here's an example function which illustrates the logic:

```
function q61401249
  C1 = 1;
  C2 = 2;
  x = [1 1 2];
  y = [2 3 4];

  str_in = 'delta_P=C1-C2;velocity=diff(y)./diff(x);';
  str_sp = strsplit(str_in,';');
  str_sp = str_sp(1:end-1);

  for i = 1:length(str_sp)
     s = split(str_sp(i),'=');
     assignin('base',s{1},eval(s{2}));
  end
end
```

when you run the function, you will see that two new variables have been created in the base workspace, `delta_P` and `velocity` as desired.

Of course the assumption here is that the equation is well formed, for instance that there aren't two `=` signs.

Comment: Nice. I would probably add a check to ensure `s{2}` doesn't have a `=` in it. Assigning could modify one of the functions used in the loop, breaking the code (for example `split=1`). I guess if the user wants to evaluate `delete('*')`, than that's their own problem, so I wouldn't worry about those type of problem with `eval`.

Comment: You are welcome Eric. As Cris correctly points out, of course the assumption here is that the equation is correctly formed (I assume you are running some validation on it before hand right?).